# FileTransfer causes an exception when trying to handle the response

Tags: android, cordova, native

I'm getting a BufferedInputStream error when trying to upload an image with Android(2.3.3).

**Sample Code**

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "image";
options.chunkedMode = false;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(imageURI, "https://192.168.1.128:5000/", function(resp) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
, function(e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}, options);
```

**Exception**

```
> java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed    at
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.streamClosed(BufferedInputStream.java:116)
>   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:274) 
>   at
> org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.UnknownLengthHttpInputStream.read(UnknownLengthHttpInputStream.java:40)
>   at
> org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.AbstractHttpInputStream.read(AbstractHttpInputStream.java:56)
>   at java.io.DataInputStream.readLine(DataInputStream.java:310)   at
> org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.upload(FileTransfer.java:286)     at
> org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.execute(FileTransfer.java:85)     at
> org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:192) 
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

After some search it appears to be an issue in Android 2.3.x (I was testing on 2.3.3). But I really want to find solution for my app.

So please kindly help to find the solution.

Comment: are you trying in device or emulator ?

Comment: Yes, I am. I test it both emulator and devices. For device that has version 2.3.3, it is error, and it is ok for version 4.x, and so do I test on the version 2.3.4 in the emulator. It means that it will curse  error only on android 2.3.3.

Comment: when you are testing it on device, is your device connected via WiFi ?

Comment: Yes, sure. I connect it via WiFi